# 2 columns with exchangeable values: in() vs and

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table where 2 columns represent user-IDs. The order of the IDs can be either way (depends on who initiated the process) 
I need to retrieve the rows for a combination of 2 users (either way).

To test I added a key on (user1, user2) and one on (user2, user1) but it ends up using neither.

My question is, what do you guys think the quickest/lowest overhead would be?

The "traditional" way:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (user1 = 1 AND user2 = 2) OR (user1 = 2 AND user2 = 1)
```

Or with in():

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user1 IN (1, 2) AND user2 IN (1, 2)
```

I'm operating under the assumption here that a no records exist where user1 = user2, so unless I'm missing something both should result in the correct records.

Edit: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6368c/2)

Comment: just run `explain select ...`and see for yourself.

Comment: explain is what told me that it results in a simple query (which is good already) but that no indexes are used. Which is why I'm posing the question here.

Comment: The first query can use an index if MySQL manages to figure out that it should use an index merge. The second query should be able to use it. Post the actual query plans and the table structure (a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) will be helpful too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema and queries are fine, MySQL just chooses to not use indexes when you have only a few rows.

[Updated fiddle with a few more rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/955d12/1)

Comment: That explains a lot. Had no idea that you needed a minimum amount of rows for the indexes to work. Both queries seem fine but the "legacy" version results in the correct recordset right away. Guess we have a winner. Thank you!

Comment: Choosing an index is somewhat complicated and depends on the contents of the table. When your index is listed in the "possible indexes" column in the query plan but it's not used it means that MySQL decided it will be faster to not use it. Most of the time it decides correctly (in this case too). You need to be aware of that when you test/debug index usage.